# Allocating data in Array with same length string

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I am stuck in allocating data in array.
for example i have 100 words in paragraph now i want to make array which contain 10 words in each array slot but not break words mean "Hello" in one slot would be "hel" and in second slot rest of word "lo".

Can anyone know how to implement it?

my paragraph look like

\r\n    hi *how* **are you**\r\n        whats going on
\r\n        \r\n        Google Translate API for .NET 0.4 alpha
\r\n        ¶\r\n\r\nDescription:\r\n\r\n**Provides a simple, unofficial, .NET Framework API** for using Google Ajax Language API service.\r\n\r\nFeature:\r\n        
\r\n        * tyle5\">Support all functions of Google Ajax Language API. \r\n        
\r\n        * CLS compatible. It can be used by any .NET languages (VB.NET, C++/CLI etc.) \r\n\r\nVersions: Google Search API for .NET comes in different versions for the various .NET frameworks. * .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile.
\r\n * .NET Framework 2.0
\r\n * .NET Compact Framework 3.5
\r\n * Silverlight 3.0 \r\n\r\n        
\r\n        Example:\r\n\r\n    string text = \"我喜欢跑步。\";\r\n        
\r\n        TranslateClient client = new TranslateClient(/* Enter the URL of your site here */);\r\n    string translated = client.Translate(text, Language.ChineseSimplified, Language.English);\r\n    Console.WriteLine(translated);\r\n    // I like running.                \r\n                   \r\n        
\r\n        
\r\n                   \r\n    "

Comment: So if your future code was given the string: "Hello this is more than ten words and break now. Look at that!" the result would be an array `["Hello this is more than ten words and break now.", "Look at that!", ...]`? Is there are reason you need arrays? Using a `List<string>` for this would probably save you some headache.

Comment: you want to randomly split words or only store 3 chars per array entry or are you going on syllables?

Comment: yes, basically i want that the array contain same size words even the paragraph contain more than 100 words.

Comment: Luke i didn't get your point can you please explain?

Comment: If you have 12 words how should it split the words?

Comment: Hi Emaad, you broke "Hello" into "Hel" and "lo", I was wondering if you wanted to split the words in a specific way, or have I misread your question? could you show what you have so far?

Comment: pabuc: then new array splot would be created and it cotain next two words.

Comment: luke: i mean that each splot last word would be complete work not half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this. If not, please let me know.

```
char separator = ' ';
int length = 10;
var splitted = paragraph.Split(separator);
List<string[]> arrays = new List<string[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length / length + 1; i++)
{
    arrays.Add(splitted.Where((x, y) => y >= i * length && y < (i + 1) * length)
        .Select( word => word + separator).ToArray());
}

foreach (var arr in arrays)
{
    foreach (var cell in arr)
    {
        Console.Write(cell);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Andrzej:why we need to split to paragraph as it contain style tags too.

Comment: @Emaad Ali The natural way to split a text is to split it by ' '. I can't advise you unless I don't know how does your paragraph string look like.

Comment: Andrzej:i inserted my paragraph.

Comment: @Emaad Ali You must decide on which characters you need to split the words, choose them and pass to `Split` method